# How to declare a variable that spans multiple lines

Tags: c++, variables

I'm attempting to initialise a `string` variable in C++, and the value is so long that it's going to exceed the 80 character per line limit I'm working to, so I'd like to split it to the next line, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I know that when splitting the contents of a stream across multiple lines, the syntax goes like

```
cout << "This is a string"
           << "This is another string";
```

Is there an equivalent for variable assignment, or do I have to declare multiple variables and concatenate them?

**Edit**: I misspoke when I wrote the initial question. When I say 'next line', I'm just meaning the next line of the script. When it is printed upon execution, I would like it to be on the same line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply break the line like this:

```
string longText("This is a "
    "very very very "
    "long text");
```

In the C family, whitespaces are insignificant, so you can freely use character literals spanning multiple lines this way.

Comment: Precision: the compiler will consider those 3 shards as a single C-string element, therefore the "concatenation" will not involve any runtime operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this:

```
const char * str = "First phrase, "
       "Second phrase, "
       "Third phrase";
```

Answer (score 1):

It can also simply be

```
cout << "This is a string"
        "This is another string";
```